# How to render a transparent gif pixel in Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Coming from a Rails background I was hoping I could render a transparent pixel gif. To do this on Rails I simply

```
gif_data = "GIF89a\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\xFF\x00\xC0\xC0\xC0\x00\x00\x00!\xF9\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x012\x00;"
respond_to do |format|
  format.gif { render text: gif_data, content_type: "image/gif" }
end
```

Would appreciate some cleaner way to do it than my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some googling and learning string encodings. I converted the Hex code of the actual transparent gif

```
47 49 46 38 39 61 01 00 01 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF 21 F9 04 01 00 00 00 00 2C 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 02 01 44 00 3B
```

using [Hexate](https://github.com/rjsamson/hexate) package into this

```
<<71, 73, 70, 56, 57, 97, 1, 0, 1, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 33, 249, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 68, 0, 59>>
```

so to use this in a Phoenix Controller I can

```
gif_data = <<71, 73, 70, 56, 57, 97, 1, 0, 1, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 33, 249, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 68, 0, 59>>
conn = put_resp_content_type(conn, "image/gif")
text conn, gif_data
```

Comment: Instead of `text/2`, call `send_resp(conn, 200, git_data)`. Same result at the end but the latter is semantically correct. :)

Comment: I have troubles testing it. Whenever the assertion against response body fails it tries to print the failure message to the terminal, but it raises `ArgumentError` because `IO.puts` (actually `:io.put_chars` which is used internally) can't handle such input.